# ¿Por qué se separan los apellidos con "y de"?

Tags: legislación, genealogía

En el nombre:

> María Marcela Lagarde y de los Ríos

"Lagarde y de los Ríos", ¿son los 2 apellidos?, ¿o es un solo apellido? ¿O es el apellido después de casarse? Nunca había visto un apellido así.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Son *dos apellidos* <sup>(1)</sup> **Lagarde** y <sup>(2)</sup> **de los Ríos**.

Por mucho tiempo en España, oficialmente (a propósitos administrativos) los apellidos paternos y maternos iban con una *y* intercalada.

Hoy día, hay varios sistemas en uso en el mundo hispanohablante.  Pero vamos a pensarlo un poco para ver qué razón podría haber.

Para un hombre, no habría ningún problema con un nombre como *Juan José Lagarde de los Ríos* porque es evidente que *Lagarde* es el primer apellido de su padre y que *de los Ríos* es el primer apellido de su madre.

No obstante, para las mujeres, en algunos lugares/tiempos (antiguamente en Cataluña, y sigue vigente en México, si no recuerdo mal — que me corrijan en caso contrario), es/era normal que una mujer, después de casarse, deje/dejase el apellido heredado de su madre, adoptando en su lugar el primer apellido de su esposo con un *de* antepuesto.  Por eso, sería posible que se pensase que una mujer con el nombre de *María Marcela Lagarde de los Ríos* era casada a un tal Sr. de los Ríos.

Para evitar confusión, ya que el apellido es *de los Ríos* y no *los Ríos* con un *de* de matrimonio antepuesto, puede ser que ella optara por el uso del *y* para que constase que el *de los Ríos* era apellido suyo de nacimiento.  Como todavía se emplea tanto *de* como *y* para hacer evidente que un nombre es apellido y no nombre, este uso no sería muy raro.  Igualmente, como *Lagarde* es apellido extranjero, puede que esta mujer pensase que a algunos les parecería como un nombre extranjero en vez de apellido, y optó por el *y* (en vez del más común *de*) para evitar la cacofonía de *Lagarde de de los Ríos*.

Pero que conste, lo de arriba es hipótesis, puede haber muchas otras razones históricas o meramente estéticas (por ejemplo, que le pareciese sencillamente más bonito y ya nada más) por el uso.

Comment: Pero espera una respuesta de otra persona — yo no soy experto en geneología

Comment: No serás experto en genealogía, pero tu explicación es muy razonable. La realidad es que el origen de los apellidos es muy variado, como también lo es su ortografía (muchas veces un mero error del Registro Civil ha generado nuevas variantes). Y hablando de "y" tenemos, sin ir más lejos, la casa reinante de España, "Borbón y Borbón".

Comment: En mi partida civil de matrimonio, de 2005, tanto mi nombre como el de mi mujer llevan una _y_ entre los dos apellidos. Si se ha dejado de hacer ha sido hace relativamente poco.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado [una página sobre genealogía](https://www.genealogiahispana.com/apellidos/cuando-usar-y-entre-los-apellidos/) que lo explica muy bien. Copiaré aquí las partes más importantes.

> El origen de esta duda se debe a lo que disponía el Registro Civil al determinar que en todas las inscripciones los apellidos *se expresarán intercalando la copulativa “Y”*. Pero el motivo de esta disposición se debió, en realidad, a una cuestión práctica ya que desde 1861 se había legislado por la Administración española que en los instrumentos públicos los individuos debían figurar con sus apellidos paterno y materno y, como señala un manual legislativo de ese mismo año, *no debe omitirse nunca la consonante “y” entre el apellido paterno y materno, porque en España son muy frecuentes los apellidos dobles.

Ante la pregunta de por qué hay personas que a día de hoy siguen usando la *y* entre los apellidos, comenta:

> La partícula es usada de forma personal, que no oficial, por dos motivos. Por una parte, se utiliza en las personas cuyo primer apellido puede ser también un nombre de pila, para evitar confusiones. Entre los casos más conocidos podemos citar a Santiago Ramón y Cajal, José María Gabriel y Galán o Francisco Tomás y Valiente.
>
> También es útil, como en tiempos pasados, para que no se produzca la reiteración de la partícula “de” cuando ésta precede a los dos apellidos, por ejemplo, Don Felipe de Borbón y Grecia o José María de Oriol y Urquijo. Teniendo en cuenta que actualmente muy pocos apellidos españoles empiezan por “de”, la coincidencia de ambos muy rara vez se produce.
>
> Salvo estos dos supuestos, el uso de la partícula “Y” que hacen algunas personas al indicar sus apellidos es algo meramente estético, sin ningún otro fundamento.

Curioso, dado que es mi caso precisamente el de tener un primer apellido que coincide con un nombre, yo podría decir que soy *Carlos Alejo y Ramírez*.